# Как можно поймать сочетание кнопка клавиатуры+кнопка мыши?

Tags: .net, winforms

Вроде, имеется только 2 независимых события:

1. От клавиатуры
2. От мыши

А как поймать определенную комбинацию? Скажем, хочу на Q+Mouse Click что-то повесить.

Есть такая идея:

Сделать поле в которое при нажатии кнопки клавиатуры будет писаться кнопка, а при отпуске обнулятся, а затем при обработке события от мыши проводить анализ этого поля.

Т.е комбинирование 3-ех событий.

Это рабочее решение или есть вариант проще?

Comment: Вариант с одним событием: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984522/how-to-get-iskeydown-method-to-work-in-c-sharp

Comment: Вариант звучит как неплохой, однако если нажать кнопку мыши, а потом кнопку клавиатуры, ваше событие не сработает. Если это ожидаемое поведение, то ваш вариант вполне рабочий. Про вариант попроще - не могу сказать.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko а какие есть альтернативные варианты, что бы оно сработало в любом порядке? Можно по идее, еще статус нажатой кнопки мыши записывать и в обработчики клавиши мыши и клавиатуру засунуть функцию, которая будет вызывать и смотреть на признаки и делать какие-то действия. По идее в этом случае будет всегда работать.

Comment: @iluxa1810 так оно действительно должно работать. Других альтернатив с ходу и не вижу. Если такой вариант работает, то почему бы и нет?

Answer (score 2):

Определить нажата ли клавиша можно с помощью [`Keyboard.IsKeyDown`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown?view=netframework-4.8).

Для использования `Keyboard` нужно будет подключить библиотеки `PresentationCore` и `WindowBase`.

После этого можно проверять зажата ли клавиша в обработчике события мыши:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var form = new Form { Text = "Click Me" };
        form.Click += (s, e) =>  form.Text = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Q) ? "Q Click" : "Just a click";
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну это не совсем чистое решение... Тащить один фреймворк в другой фреймворк...

Comment: @iluxa1810 Согласен. Решения на windows forms существенно проще Вашего я тогда не придумал.